# Simplifying Loading drawables from grid view

Tags: java, android, gridview, imageview

I have a large amount of resources in the drawable folder of my project, all these resources are displayed in `GridView`, now when user select the image from the `GridView`the image should load up and show in the screen. The problem is my class has become incredibly large by just having to do an "if" oriented programming to know which image was clicked. I Believe there is a more efficiente way to load up resources using `HashMap` or alike.

here is a little example of only one menu:

```
secondList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg20, View arg21, int arg22, long arg23) {
                clearbackground2();
                arg21.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fondoselected);
                ((TextView) arg21.findViewById(R.id.textoItem)).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#8fb5e3"));
                if (arg22 == 0) {
                    final int menuSecondSelected = arg22;
                    txtThirdTitleList.setText("Curvas");
                    thirdList.setAdapter(new SketchMenuSideAdapter((Activity) view.getContext(), getResources().getStringArray(R.array.viaCurva), getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.viaCurvaIcon), 3));
                    thirdList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> argTrh20, View argTrh21, int arg22, long arg2Trh3) {
                            if (arg22 == 0) {
                                addNewImage(menuSecondSelected, "1carril", null, null);
                            }
                            if (arg22 == 1) {
                                addNewImage(menuSecondSelected, "2carriles", null, null);
                            }
                            if (arg22 == 2) {
                                addNewImage(menuSecondSelected, "3carriles", null, null);
                            }
                            if (arg22 == 3) {
                                addNewImage(menuSecondSelected, "abierta1", null, null);
                            }
                            if (arg22 == 4) {
                                addNewImage(menuSecondSelected, "abierta2", null, null);
                            }
                            if (arg22 == 5) {
                                addNewImage(menuSecondSelected, "abierta3", null, null);
                            }
                            if (arg22 == 6) {
                                addNewImage(menuSecondSelected, "abierta4", null, null);
                            }
                            if (arg22 == 7) {
                                addNewImage(menuSecondSelected, "abierta5", null, null);
                            }
                            if (arg22 == 8) {
                                addNewImage(menuSecondSelected, "cerrada1", null, null);
                            }
                            if (arg22 == 9) {
                                addNewImage(menuSecondSelected, "cerrada2", null, null);
                            }
                            if (arg22 == 10) {
                                addNewImage(menuSecondSelected, "cerrada3", null, null);
                            }
                            if (arg22 == 11) {
                                addNewImage(menuSecondSelected, "cerrada4", null, null);
                            }
                            if (arg22 == 12) {
                                addNewImage(menuSecondSelected, "cerrada5", null, null);
                            }
                            if (arg22 == 13) {
                                addNewImage(menuSecondSelected, "carril1", null, null);
                            }
                            if (arg22 == 14) {
                                addNewImage(menuSecondSelected, "carril2", null, null);
                            }
                            if (arg22 == 15) {
                                addNewImage(menuSecondSelected, "carril3", null, null);
                            }
                            if (arg22 == 16) {
                                addNewImage(menuSecondSelected, "carril4", null, null);
                            }
                            if (arg22 == 17) {
                                addNewImage(menuSecondSelected, "carril5", null, null);
                            }
                            if (arg22 == 18) {
                                addNewImage(menuSecondSelected, "carril6", null, null);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
```

There is about 6000 lines of only this kind of menus, can anybody suggest a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using a [SparseArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html). It is a collection in the Android platform that maps integers to objects. In function it is equal to a `Map<Integer, Object>`. A HashMap is (marginally) faster but the SparseArray is optimised for memory usage.

This improves readability because you define and fill the map just once, then you get the corresponding value with just one method.

```
SparseArray<String> menuMap = new SparseArray<>();
menuMap.put(0, "1carril");
menuMap.put(1, "2carril");
menuMap.put(2, "3carril");
menuMap.put(3, "abierta1");
menuMap.put(4, "abierta2");
menuMap.put(5, "abierta3");
menuMap.put(6, "abierta4");
menuMap.put(7, "abierta5");
menuMap.put(8, "carril1");
menuMap.put(9, "carril2");
menuMap.put(10, "carril3");
```

Then just get the mapped value where you need it:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> argTrh20, View argTrh21, int arg22, long arg2Trh3) {
    String value = menuMap.get(arg22);
    if(value != null) {
        addNewImage(menuSecondSelected, value, null, null);
    }
}
```

---

This would be appropriate if you have enough items. This will greatly increase the readability where you need the value. You do still have to add all the pairs to the map first, but that can be done out of the way (even in some other class). You can also change or add new values easier.

In terms of efficiency: you should at least be using if-else or a switch statement. Other than that it won't vary that much, it may even favor towards the map if there are enough items. But this shouldn't be a real concern here.  Readability and maintainability are more important than a tiny efficiency difference.

---

Edit: It can actually be even shorter. I only now realized that `arg22` is just the position in a list.
First of all, name your parameters appropriately. `argTrh20`, `argTrh21` and `arg22` are horrible names.
But, because the position will always be between 0 and some value, you can just use an array. You don't need to map the ints to values because that can just be the position in the array.
Now you can define it in less lines and with less unnecessary code:

```
String[] menuValues = {"1carril", "2carril", "3carril", "rest here", "..." };
```

Getting the value is now reduced to:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    if(position < menuValues.length) { // this is just a defensive check. If you are sure the array is the same length as the max amount of items, this can be omitted.
        addNewImage(menuSecondSelected, menuValues[position], null, null);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Amazing this is the kind of answer I was looking for, I will try to implement it and see how it goes

Comment: @Juanca Glad you liked it. I just edited my answer with another, shorter, example

Comment: I just reduced my class from 6398 lines to 2835, and implemented another class only for the String arrays of only 650 lines, that was an amazing improve, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

For Performance you could use a switch instead of the if

For readability so your main class isn't that large

Make a new class for this:

main:

```
thirdList.setOnItemClickListener(new clicked())
```

OnItemClicked class:

```
public Class clicked implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> argTrh20, View argTrh21, int arg22, long arg2Trh3) {
                        if (arg22 == 0) {
                            addNewImage(menuSecondSelected, "1carril", null, null);
                        }
                        if (arg22 == 1) {
                            addNewImage(menuSecondSelected, "2carriles", null, null);
                        }
                        if (arg22 == 2) {
                            addNewImage(menuSecondSelected, "3carriles", null, null);
                        }
                        if (arg22 == 3) {
                            addNewImage(menuSecondSelected, "abierta1", null, null);
                        }
                        if (arg22 == 4) {
                            addNewImage(menuSecondSelected, "abierta2", null, null);
                        }
                        if (arg22 == 5) {
                            addNewImage(menuSecondSelected, "abierta3", null, null);
                        }
                        if (arg22 == 6) {
                            addNewImage(menuSecondSelected, "abierta4", null, null);
                        }
                        if (arg22 == 7) {
                            addNewImage(menuSecondSelected, "abierta5", null, null);
                        }
                        if (arg22 == 8) {
                            addNewImage(menuSecondSelected, "cerrada1", null, null);
                        }
                        if (arg22 == 9) {
                            addNewImage(menuSecondSelected, "cerrada2", null, null);
                        }
                        if (arg22 == 10) {
                            addNewImage(menuSecondSelected, "cerrada3", null, null);
                        }
                        if (arg22 == 11) {
                            addNewImage(menuSecondSelected, "cerrada4", null, null);
                        }
                        if (arg22 == 12) {
                            addNewImage(menuSecondSelected, "cerrada5", null, null);
                        }
                        if (arg22 == 13) {
                            addNewImage(menuSecondSelected, "carril1", null, null);
                        }
                        if (arg22 == 14) {
                            addNewImage(menuSecondSelected, "carril2", null, null);
                        }
                        if (arg22 == 15) {
                            addNewImage(menuSecondSelected, "carril3", null, null);
                        }
                        if (arg22 == 16) {
                            addNewImage(menuSecondSelected, "carril4", null, null);
                        }
                        if (arg22 == 17) {
                            addNewImage(menuSecondSelected, "carril5", null, null);
                        }
                        if (arg22 == 18) {
                            addNewImage(menuSecondSelected, "carril6", null, null);
                        }
                    }
}
```